# iOS App Accessibility- How to make voiceover to read out the screen name when view appears?

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover

One of the requirement for the app I am developing is, whenever user navigates or sees a screen, then voice over should announce information about that screen. And it should announce only once before focus goes to some element in the view.

Could someone help or give some ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have your `self` as `isAccessibilityElement = true`.

Make sure to have `accessibilityLabel` to the `self.title` which will voice over the screen name.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.title = "TEST"
    self.isAccessibilityElement = true
    self.accessibilityLabel = self.title
}
```